# How to add own Parameters and Response values in the drf-yasg library for swagger documentation?

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I use the [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library to generate project documentation for the developer front-ends. I can't figure out how to add my data to the fields **Parameters** and **Responses**

For example, this class

```
class VendorsCreateView(APIView):
    """
    :param:
            data = {
            "vendor_name": "TestName",
            "country": "Belarus",
            "nda": "2020-12-12",
            "parent": "",
            "contacts": [{"contact_name": "Mrk", "phone": "2373823", "email": "dRqT@rgmail.com"},
                         {"contact_name": "Uio", "phone": "34567", "email": "rdq@gmail.com"}
                         ]
        }
    :return: swagger name
    """
```

But I don't exactly get what I want
[image]

How do I add these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`@swagger_auto_schema` decorator](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, that question was still relevant. Could you tell  how to add a field  `parameters`? I'm trying this way but nothing is displayed (both operation_description and operation_description work). `@swagger_auto_schema(operation_description="partial_update description override", responses={404: 'slug not found'}, parameters="test")`

Comment: Use `request_body` argument with a serializer or a schema. Checkout `testproj` code on drf-yasg GitHub, e.g.  https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/d2cc0a348c2d9505a19e6ee7acea1e86fb63d277/testproj/users/views.py lines 26 and 49.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it will help someone who wants extra parameter in GET-request - you should use argument "manual_parameters" in drf-yasg, e.g. field you want to order by to:

```
order_by = openapi.Parameter('order_by', openapi.IN_QUERY,
                             description="field you want to order by to",
                             type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

@swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[order_by])
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

swagger:
[image]